# sftp mput exit code 11 issue while file transfer

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, file-transfer, exit-code

I am transferring .done file from server A to B and the command exists with Exit Code : 11, .done file being transfered at 01:30:04 am

```
    sftp> mput /export/test-n-20170203.done
    test-n-20170203.done | 28B | 330B/s | TOC: 00:00:00
    sftp> exit

    On the receiving server B, .done file details are as follows
      Size: 28              Blocks: 2          IO Block: 8192   regular file
    Device: 980c75bh/159434587d     Inode: 15595212    Links: 1
    Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (2000002519/u)   Gid: (10002004/   m)
    Access: 2017-02-06 01:35:46.752507000 -0500
    Modify: 2017-02-06 01:30:13.782729000 -0500
    Change: 2017-02-06 01:35:46.759508000 -0500
```

If the file is sftp'd multiple times it does not give any error and exit code is 0 but sometimes I get exit code 11.

What should be done to prevent exit code 11?

Comment: what is the verbose output when it fails ? it might be -v / -d flag

Comment: How do you test the exit code? The `sftp` actually only ever returns 1 or 0 (unless it crashes).

Comment: @vin For `sftp`, it's `-v`. And you can repeat the `v` to get more verbose log. Like `-vvv`.